# How do I type any text in Windows Command and and move to the next line without getting "unrecognized internal or external command"?

Tags: command-line

I have seen a lot of scambaiting videos on youtube and have noticed that some scammers run the command

```
dir /s
```

or

```
tree
```

to cause the computer to list all files on the drive, and while the command is executed, the scammer will type something like `NO SECURITY FOUND. COMPUTER INFECTED, NETWORK COMPROMISED` etc, then once the command is finished, the buffered text will appear at the bottom of the screen, as if it was produced by the command.

In some cases, the "injected" message is followed by the infamous

> `XXXX is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.`

but I have seen other videos where the injected message appears like this:

```
C:\> COMPUTER HACKED, NETWORK INFECTED, IP COMPROMISED

c:\>

C:\>
```

It seems that the scammer was able to type the injected message, somehow move to the next line twice without causing the command to get verified.

I tried to mimic this behavior but I failed. I tried hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> which did cause the cursor to move to a new line and the error message did not appear, however,that caused what I typed to be wiped out.

My question is: how can I type an arbitrary text in the command line, and move to the next line without triggering the validation of the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while typing the command, the cursor will move down to the next line without executing the command.